# How to tell if the user has finally quit all your activities in android application

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, oncreate, onpause

I want to set ringvolume to `0` when a user opens my teaching application then return it to the original volume when the user quits. What's the best way of doing this? 
I can set volume to `0` with no problems 
The difficulty is knowing when to restore it, my application has multiple activities which are used frequently and I'm worried about the performance implications of setting the volume to `0` for every `onCreate()`and restoring it for every `onStop()` It also seems messy and labour intensive! 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

### As an addendum,

I've thought of a way of doing half of it:
create a boolean `leaving =true;`  
when user opens new intent for my next activity set this to `true` 
in the `onPause()` use this variable to check if the user is "leaving" or simply opening another one of "my activities" 
This still means that I must set ringer to silent in all my `onResume()`s 
Does anyone have any further solutions?

Comment: You should definitely restore the level during OnPause or OnStop as appropriate - the user will not appreciate the volume being muted if they switch to another app while keeping yours in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your app may not always be at the top of the activity stack when it is running. What if the user switches to another app, or some alarm or phone call takes over the focus?

Here are some ways I would go about achieving what you are trying to do (expanded from the comments below):

### Option 1:

If the mute action does not affect the performance of your app (from my own experience I suspect it won't), you could simplify the solution you suggested in your question with a single abstract base class, overloading *onResume()* and *onPause()* to ensure you capture the event when the user [returns to your already created](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks) activity:

```
public abstract class TeachingAppActivity extends Activity {
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // Perform mute action here...
    }

    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // Perform unmute action here...
    }
}

public class MyActivity1 extends TeachingAppActivity {
} 

public class MyActivity2 extends TeachingAppActivity {
}
```

This would simplify your code, but keep the action contained within your activities: If another app grabs the focus, the ringer will be restored. If the user returns to MyActivity2, the ringer will be muted again.

### Option 2:

If the mute action is indeed going to affect the performance of your app, or you simply don't want to perform execute it in every activity's *onResume()* and *onPause()*, you could instead use a [worker thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#WorkerThreads) and a [status bar notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html):

1. In each Activity *onResume()*; start an AsyncTask (or Runnable task), you could subclass Activity to share this code with your other activities.
2. This worker thread **first checks**, then mutes, the volume. If the volume is changed, it then displays a notification icon that informs the user that the volume has been muted.
3. The worker thread can then terminate, having performed this check and action without affecting UI performance.
4. The volume will remain muted for the duration of the app, if the user jumps to another app (or an incoming call/message takes the focus), he/she is still aware that the volume is muted because the notification icon is still present.
5. If the user presses the notification icon, a broadcast intent restores the volume. This could also be triggered by a button or action within your app.

If the user presses the Home button, or presses the Back button repeatedly in your app, the volume will not be restored. This is intentional, since they have not "quit" your app, they have simply moved to the bottom of the activity stack. The rule will be: as long as the notification icon is visible, the volume has been muted by your app.

The added benefit here is that if another app changes the volume, your app will always check when **any** of your activities receives the focus again.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. It seems like you've thought it out well. However, I can't believe there isn't a simpler solution! And as regards processing, will starting an asynctask for each activity actually take less time than silencing the ringer? Maybe I'm over-thinking this and should just go ahead with muting and unmuting for every activity! I was hoping there was a way I could check the size of the activity stack when leaving each activity maybe?

Comment: This is a tricky bit to fully comprehend in the Android platform: Imagine your app is a website, and the activity stack is like your browser history. With a website, you have a start point but (in practice) no end, you can't tell where the user is hopping into your website, and how they might leave. In fact, you don't even know if they might visit another website and come back. This is the reason you need a stateless solution for the action you are trying to achieve; because it affects other apps as well as your own.

Comment: Using the ASyncTask was an optimisation tweak I threw in to demonstrate what you might do if performance was an issue (as you hinted in your question). In reality, I suspect you'll find altering the volume in the UI thread will have little impact on user experience. Probably best to test this in your app. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks again Sean. Option one was perfect for what I wanted, there seems to be no extra delay changing ringer mode (I was worried that having an SGS with it's usual write speed lags that this would be a problem) I've implemented that solution and learnt some more about java in the process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the function

```
@Override
public void onResme() {
super.onResme();
//mute volume here
}
```

It will help you to make what you want

Answer (score -2):

use the function

```
@Override
public void onDestry() {
  super.onDestroy();
  // re-enable sound here
}
```

in your main activity, so you can response to both activity "quit" and "kill by a task manager".

Comment: -1. This is exactly what he doesn't want to do. He points out in the question that he lots of different activities, and doesn't want to toggle the volume on and off when each activity starts or stops.

Comment: whats wrong? did you read the first line of the question?

"I want to set ringvolume to 0 when a user opens my teaching application then return it to the original volume when the user quits. What's the best way of doing this?"

Comment: The `onDestroy()` of the "main" activity is not a good way of determining if any of the *other* activities are running.

Comment: ah ok, i misunderstand that :)